# How to sum numerical values within a vector?

Tags: r, vector, nan

I have a vector `a` containing the following values:
`3.00 6.00 NaN -7.00 56.00 32.00 ... Inf 7.00 15.00 NaN Inf 4.00`

How is it possible to sum only numerical values (without `NaN`s, `Inf` and so on) within such a vector?
I've tried `sum(a,na.rm=TRUE)`, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want

```
a <- c(NaN,NA,1,Inf)
sum(a[is.finite(a)])
```

(`sum(a, na.rm=TRUE)` takes care of `NA` and `NaN` values, but not `Inf`/`-Inf`)

This answer is also given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508889/how-to-count-number-of-numeric-values-in-a-column/1510367#1510367), but the question is not a duplicate ...